# No registered dependency injection service exception in a Mediator design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mediator

I am trying (already lost a day) to implement my own light version of the Mediator design pattern, and I am encountering an issue with calling a service from the DI (Dependency Injection) container, getting a 'No registered service' exception.

The **main goal** here is to have a Mediator Service which sends requests to their handlers with the **response type** **defined** **in the request itself** (for cleaner code).

First, I created three necessary interfaces:

The `IRequest` interface, which defines the response type `TResponse` (this is the most important part of the task/problem). This interface will be attached to every request implementation in order to define both the request itself and **its return type**.

```
interface IRequest<out TResponse> { }
```

The `IRequestHandler` where `TRequest` is equivalent to the implementation of above `IRequest` interface).

```
interface IRequestHandler<in TRequest, out TResponse> where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    TResponse Handle(TRequest request);
}
```

The Mediator `ISender` interface which just sends a `Request` to its `RequestHandler` and returning some `Response`.

```
interface ISender
{
    TResponse Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request);
}
```

Second, I implemented above interfaces.

A parameterless `Request` which implements `IRequest` with string as a return type (or any other type).

```
class Request : IRequest<string> { }
```

`RequstHandler` which implements its `IRequestHandler`.

```
class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler<Request, string>
{
    public string Handle(Request request)
    {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

`Sender` which implements `ISender` interface.

```
class Sender : ISender
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Sender(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public TResponse Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request)
    {
        // HERE IS THE ERROR
        var handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRequestHandler<IRequest<TResponse>,
                                                          TResponse>>();

        return handler.Handle(request);
    }
}
```

Finally, I registered services as:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<ISender, Sender>();
services.AddScoped<IRequestHandler<Request, string>, RequestHandler>();
```

And when I execute below statement:

```
_sender.Send(new Request());
```

ERROR: No service for type ConsoleApp1.IRequestHandler`2[ConsoleApp1.IRequest`1[System.String],System.String]' has been registered. (I am using console app just for test)

The error itself is quite straightforward, as I am not implementing `IRequest` but `Request`, so something like `TRequest` will probably make more sense. However, what is **the** **most important to me** is to be able to send a `Request` with its return type in the format of:

```
_sender.Send(new Request()); // return type is known based on IRequest interface
```

and that the return type is immediately recognized based on the `IRequest` interface without specifying it explicitly, like:

```
_sender.Send<Request, string>(new Request());
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering

```
IRequestHandler<Request, string>
```

And you are trying to resolve

```
IRequestHandler<IRequest<TResponse>, TResponse>>
```

Which are 2 different things

If you change the interface to something like this

```
interface ISender
{
    TResponse Send<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request) where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>;
}
```

Now you have access to the actual implemention type.

But note that the implementation of `ISender` will have to be much more complicated for this to work.

*UPDATED ANSWER AFTER COMMENT

The way that I solved this in a personal project was using a generic proxy, mediator solves this using the .net `Activator`.

This is my version of the `ISender`

```
internal sealed class CommandBus : ICommandBus
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CommandBus(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(ICommand command) => await SendAsync(command, CancellationToken.None);

    public async Task SendAsync(ICommand command, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);
        var commandHandlerProxyType =
            typeof(CommandHandlerProxy<,>).MakeGenericType(commandHandlerType, commandType);

        var commandHandlerProxy =
            (ICommandHandlerProxy) _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(commandHandlerProxyType);
        await commandHandlerProxy.Handle(command, token);
    }

    public async Task<TResult> SendAsync<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command) =>
        await SendAsync(command, CancellationToken.None);

    public async Task<TResult> SendAsync<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var commandHandlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(commandType, typeof(TResult));
        var commandHandlerProxyType =
            typeof(CommandHandlerGenericProxy<,,>).MakeGenericType(commandHandlerType, commandType,
                typeof(TResult));

        var commandHandlerProxy =
            (ICommandHandlerGenericProxy<TResult>) _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(commandHandlerProxyType);
        var result = await commandHandlerProxy.Handle(command, token);
        return result;
    }

    internal interface ICommandHandlerGenericProxy<TResult>
    {
        Task<TResult> Handle(ICommand command, CancellationToken token);
    }

    internal sealed class
        CommandHandlerGenericProxy<TCommandHandler, TCommand, TResult> : ICommandHandlerGenericProxy<TResult>
        where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
        where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
    {
        private readonly TCommandHandler _commandHandler;

        public CommandHandlerGenericProxy(TCommandHandler commandHandler)
        {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public async Task<TResult> Handle(ICommand command, CancellationToken token) =>
            await _commandHandler.Handle((TCommand) command, token);
    }

    internal interface ICommandHandlerProxy
    {
        Task Handle(ICommand command, CancellationToken token);
    }

    internal sealed class CommandHandlerProxy<TCommandHandler, TCommand> : ICommandHandlerProxy
        where TCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly TCommandHandler _commandHandler;

        public CommandHandlerProxy(TCommandHandler commandHandler)
        {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public async Task Handle(ICommand command, CancellationToken token) =>
            await _commandHandler.Handle((TCommand) command, token);
    }
}
```

And you need to register the generic proxies as open generics like this:

```
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(CommandBus.CommandHandlerProxy<,>));
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(CommandBus.CommandHandlerGenericProxy<,,>));
```

These are the interfaces I used

```
public interface ICommand
{
}

public interface ICommand<TResult> : ICommand
{
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    Task Handle(TCommand command, CancellationToken token);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand, TResult> where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> Handle(TCommand command, CancellationToken token);
}

public interface ICommandBus
{
    Task SendAsync(ICommand command);

    Task SendAsync(ICommand command, CancellationToken token);

    Task<TResult> SendAsync<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command);

    Task<TResult> SendAsync<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command, CancellationToken token);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly happened, but someone posted a working solution yesterday and today it is missing. Anyhow, the best would be if you can update your answer with your idea of ISender implementation. Just keep in mind that I do not want to call the Send() method with '_sender.Send<Request, string>(new Request());' but only with a cleaner version such as '_sender.Send(new Request());'.

Comment: Updated the answer, note that I originally chose not to include the implementation of `ISender` because there are multiple ways you can solve this problem and this is just one of the ways, mediator has their own way using the `Activator` class and if you want to keep things simple then you can choose the first approach which is a bit more complex on the user side but simplifies your `ISender` code a lot, because you don't have to deal with co- or contravariance I'm not sure which one applies here, I always confuse those 2 with eachother

Comment: @VedranKnezevic does this answer your question, or am I still missing something?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not have time to review your answer deeply, but my first impression is that your approach is very similar to the MediatR library, which complexity I tried to avoid. So, without using a wrapper, a shorter solution is (as somebody else answered earlier) to just update my Send() method with these corrections:
var requestType = request.GetType(); 
var handlerType = typeof(IRequestHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(requestType, typeof(TResponse)); 
var handler = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);
return ((dynamic)handler).Handle((dynamic)request);